# How to measure voice frequency (pitch) in R from a WAV file?

Tags: r, function, wav

I tried to use the analyze() from Soundgen library but it takes a lot of time to run because it analyzes everything. Is there a different library or function to get just the frequency?

Comment: The `analyze` function docs [analyze](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/soundgen/versions/1.5.0/topics/analyze) do offer a fastest approach, but looking at `analyze` there and the many inputs/assessments that constitute 'pitch', and if 'pitch' was between your bank account and the voice recognition system at your bank, how simple would you want the 'pitch' analysis to be? How long is your WAV?

Comment: And dancing with both python and r [extract pitch](https://walczak.org/tag/audio/) as another approach.

Comment: @Chris  I am using mono WAV files with 5 to 15 minute length. There is not any music or background noises, it is just one person speaking. I thought if I get the frequency of the file it would match to some extent the voice pitch. I am not trying to measure it accurately but to see how it changes...